# Why do I get error 'File does not contain a valid CIL image' when debugging from Visual Studio Code editor?

Tags: c#, macos, mono, visual-studio-code

I'm running Visual Studio Code on Max OS X and constantly seeing this error. Works fine when I run directly from Terminal using dnx .run

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
 Error Trace from Terminal   'mono' --debug  
 --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:57332  
 'Program.cs' Cannot open assembly 'Program.cs': File does not contain
 a valid CIL image.
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio? What version of Mac OS X?

Comment: Looks like you made some changes to the project configuration that changed what's being run when you start the project. It shouldn't be running `Program.cs`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a testing build of a product with many known/unknown issues. The discussion will be rather useless once a new build is shipped.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 5 is explicitly stated by Microsoft as not yet supported, and there are other debugging limitations,

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/FAQ

So wait, wait, wait.